# Implementing wait until element available in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I tried implementing to wait until the element is available (Found in Stackoverflow itself) but getting error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
> Automation error
> Unspecified error

Following is the code snippet:

```
Do
    Set testObject = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set testObject = html.getElementById("j_username")
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents
Loop While testObject Is Nothing
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because the HTML document has not fully loaded. In your do loop add this:

```
Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
Set html = IE.Document
```

only after you properly reference the loaded object will it make sense to:

```
Set testObject = html.getElementById("j_username")
```